# In which condition "Creating tmp table" and "removing tmp table" State last for long in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, mysql-5.5

I have lot of queries that shows their state **Creating tmp table** or **removing tmp table**.

My Queries are already optimized, when i run query separately it executes in less than 1 second but sometimes lot of queries stuck in this state for around 1 minute.

Whats the situation for this would happen ? And is there any variable that tune this kind of situation ?

Comment: Perhaps other connections are doing things that interfere.  Perhaps if we could see the query and the associated `SHOW CREATE TABLE` it would give us more clues, thereby letting us help you.

Comment: There is no other query. And show create table would not help as its running fine when running separately.

Comment: I agree that the `CREATE` _should not_ help, but I am hoping to get some clues.